# SQL Server Severe Errror Level 11 & 20

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A
>   severe error occurred on the current
>   command.  The results, if any, should
>   be discarded.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State
>   0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on
>   the current command.  The results, if
>   any, should be discarded.

Any tips on how to fix this? It's really bad bad because I just started building the schema and had some data in their and lost a lot of work and haven't backed up yet....

A dbcc checktable('tableName') gave me the following output:

> Msg 8967, Level 16, State 140, Line 1
>
> An internal error occurred in DBCC
>   that prevented further processing.
>   Contact Customer Support Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're worried about is the schema you might be able to get it back using REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS option of CHECKDB

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx

Meanwhile you might want to check the health of your disks.  Sounds like your getting some page corruption.  Is this on a server or a workstation?